# How to identify first time BootCompleted

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing a system application. Is there a way to identify when the device has been started for the first time? As opposed to onBootCompleted which just let's me know when the device has been restarted.

Answer (score -1):

Save a boolean value in SharedPreferences. Do the check and saving in the onCreate method.